# Setting background-blend-mode and background-color doesn't work in HTML email

Tags: css, html-email

I'm trying to create an email and set a background image on a `<td>` with low opacity.
What I've come to is:

```
<td dir="rtl" align="center" style="width:100% border: 0px; background-blend-mode: lighten; background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8); background-image:url('image_url');background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position: 50% 50%;background-size:auto; vertical-align: middle;" colspan="2">
```

This works well when I'm using it on an HTML page I've created, however, when I send this as an email to Gmail desktop web client/Inbox app on Android/Gmail app on Android the background is gone.

From what I've checked, all the properties I've set are compatible with the clients I've mentioned.

Is there another way to do this in emails?

Answer (score 1):

When designing e-mail templates you have to work as if you would build a website in the mid-90's. A lot of stuff doesn't work. Actually, there's more that not works, then what does.

A handy tool is [caniuse.email](https://caniuse.email/).

Comment: I get that, but is there any other way of doing that?

Comment: I've built a lot of e-mail templates in my life, and believe me; it's mostly not worth it to find a workaround. E-mail is not meant for funky stuff like that. If you really want to achieve an effect like that; tell the guy with photoshop to deliver the image with the effect already applied. Totally cross-browser safe, and it takes far less time to do that 500 times then it would take you to come up with a solution

Comment: that's a nice solution but the image I use is selected by the user

Comment: tell the user to blend the background :p if he is not able to, tell him to ask someone who can. and if he doesn't know someone, explain him what we've just told you; the state of e-mail templates is the state of the internet in mid '90s. How did the internet look like back then? Right, we didn't have no background-blend ;)

Comment: NP! can you please write your email so I'll be able to forward all the users 'greetings'?

Answer (score 1):

`background-blend-mode` works with IOS devices, traditional Gmail, but not a lot of mobile clients or Outlook.

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/color-background/background-blend-mode/

Check out this article to see if there's another technique that might help, but there's nothing universal that you can use.
 https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/uncategorized/css-animations-part-1/

`rgba-color` does not work with Yahoo or Outlook.

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/color-background/rgba-colors/

`positioning` does not work with most email clients.

`background-image` does not work with Outlook at all or some Android clients. However, you can get a work-around to work with Outlook using VML.

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/color-background/background-image/

Since you don't really post a code example of what you're trying to do, just a small snippet, it's hard to make suggestions on better ways to get the same effect.

Good luck.